# Elasticsearch UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder unit test with JAVA

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, junit, mockito

I tried to create some unit test that has elasticsearch update query.
I use Mockito to mock elasticsearch client and the others.

but it's always failed

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:404)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:394)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:53)
    at com.dondon.UpdateServiceImpl.lambda$updateStatus $0(UpdateServiceImpl.java:108)
```

here is my function to be tests, i use mockito to mock several object

```
@Override
public Boolean updateStatus() {
  if(elasticSearchService.isIndexExists(ElasticSearchIndexConstant.ROUTE_MANAGEMENT_MAP_INDEX)){
    UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQueryRequestBuilder = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
    updateByQueryRequestBuilder.source(ElasticSearchIndexConstant.ROUTE_MANAGEMENT_MAP_INDEX);
    updateByQueryRequestBuilder
        .script(
            new Script(
                ScriptType.INLINE, "painless, "ctx._source.status".concat("='")
                .concat("ACTIVE")
                .concat("'"),
                Collections.emptyMap()
            )
        )
        .source()
        .setQuery(
            QueryBuilders.matchQuery("FIELD", "SOME_UNIQUE_CODE")
        );

    BulkByScrollResponse response = updateByQueryRequestBuilder.get(); // this line always failed
    return true;
  }

return false;
}
```

and this is my test case to test service or function

```
@Mock
private UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQueryRequestBuilder;

@Mock
private SearchRequestBuilder searchRequest;

@Mock
private BulkByScrollResponse bulkByScrollResponse;

@Mock
private SearchResponse searchResponse;

@Test
public void updateStatusRouteManagementBasedOnAirlineConfigurationActiveTest() throws Exception {
    when(elasticSearchService.isIndexExists(ElasticSearchIndexConstant.ROUTE_MANAGEMENT_MAP_INDEX)).thenReturn(true);
    when(updateByQueryRequestBuilder.source(ElasticSearchIndexConstant.ROUTE_MANAGEMENT_MAP_INDEX)).thenReturn(updateByQueryRequestBuilder);
    when(updateByQueryRequestBuilder.script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.status='ACTIVE'",
        Collections.emptyMap()))).thenReturn(updateByQueryRequestBuilder);
    when(updateByQueryRequestBuilder.source()).thenReturn(searchRequest);
    when(searchRequest.setQuery(any())).thenReturn(searchRequest);
    when(updateByQueryRequestBuilder.get()).thenReturn(bulkByScrollResponse);
    when(updateByQueryRequestBuilder
        .source(ElasticSearchIndexConstant.ROUTE_MANAGEMENT_MAP_INDEX)
        .script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.status='ACTIVE'",
            Collections.emptyMap()))
        .source().setQuery(any())
        .get()).thenReturn(searchResponse);


    Boolean updated = updateService.updateStatus();

    assertEquals(true, updated);
}
```

Comment: Can you mention at which line exactly you are facing the exception?

Comment: BulkByScrollResponse response = updateByQueryRequestBuilder.get(); // this line always failed

i always get failed when i call get() from updateByQyeryRequestBuilder